# How to Block Wordpress from subdomain?

Tags: redirect, subdomains, user-access

I have a website with wordpress installed http://www.website.com

Wordpress is installed in my root

I also have multiple sub-domains/sub folders in my root , How do i block

wordpress from these subdomain folders

Like http:///www.website.com/sub I don't want sub to be used by wordpress....

Comment: Can you give us some code examples of what you've tried?

Comment: What do you mean by block?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `RedirectMatch 404` in your WordPress `.htaccess`:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/(sub-folder-1|sub-folder-2)(/.+)?$
```